# What does temperature coefficient of resistance depend on?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science

I tried looking up on Google if there was an expression for the temperature coefficient of resistance(TCR) of a material in terms of other fundamental factors, but couldn't find any. Specifically I am interested in knowing if the TCR can change with stress applied to the material. Any pointers or links will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are asking for a fundamental mechanism which determines the temperature coefficient of a material, then you will be disappointed, there isn't any. One can make materials with extremely wide varying tcrs and the mechanisms that lead to them are rather diverse, ranging from phonon excitation over percolation to breakdown of superconductivity.

Answer (score 2):

Resistance changes with temperature

The temperature coefficient of resistance, or TCR, is one of the main used parameters to characterize a resistor. The TCR defines the change in resistance as a function of the ambient temperature. The common way to express the TCR is in ppm/°C, which stands for parts per million per centigrade degree. The temperature coefficient of resistance is calculated as follows:

Formula temperature coefficient of a resistor: TCR = (R2-R1)e-6 / R1*(T2-T1)

Where TCR is in ppm/°C, R1 is in ohms at room temperature, R2 is resistance at operating temperature in ohms, T1 is the room temperature in °C and T2 is the operating temperature in °C. Often instead of TCR, α is used.

[image]

Graph showing average TCR for resistors
Average TCR ΔR/R in ppm for a temperature range of -55 till 25˚C and 25 till 125˚C

Read more http://www.resistorguide.com/temperature-coefficient-of-resistance/